# MVC3. How can i retrieve the data inside House Entities using this?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

```
public IList<House> GetFullList()
        {
            try
            {
                var session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();

                return session.QueryOver<House>()
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Owner).Asc
                    .List<House>();  

            }
            catch (NHibernate.ADOException nex)
            {
                log.Error(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " Error-- " + nex.ToString());
                throw new Exception(ExceptionConstants.ERR_DATABASE_ERROR);
            }
        }
```

the code above is on "PostService.css". For now i`m trying to retrieve all my data from database into a view called AllHouses() using that method. The entities of House consist. Owner, Price, Location and Description. How can i get my data into GridView. I would like to make "edit" "delete" function as well..

Comment: I don't really see why you tagged this question as an MVC 3 question. Could you also be more concise with your question?

Comment: sorry im totally new with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply by iterating through the list that the method returns. So if you call it form inside an action:

```
// This code is in your controller

using  TemplateProject.Core.Entities;
// ...

public ActionResult HouseList()
{
   // call method to retrieve the list of houses
   var service = new PostService();
   var houses = service.GetFullList();

   // this will render the view called "HouseList", passing it the 
   // list of houses as view model
   return View(houses)
}
```

And in the `HouseList` view (`HouseList.cshtml`) you can for instance iterate through
the list of houses and render them in a table:

```
@using TemplateProject.Core.Entities
@model IEnumerable<House>

<table>
   <thead>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Description</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach(var house in Model)
      {
         <tr><td>@house.Description</td></tr>
         <tr><td>@house.Price</td></tr>
      }
   </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have a Grid control you can use the `Model` property of the view to build it up.

Comment: the code is from Service.css

So if i try get all the value inside my House Table into Controller..
`code`
public ActionResult View()
{
   var houses = GetFullList();

   foreach(var house in houses)
   {
      // here you can access the properties of the 
      // current house in the loop.
   }
}
`code`
example i have "Description", "Price", "Status"
How shall i write the code? Sorry i'm new in MVC3
i wish to get a most simple way to do it.

Comment: @Xion Chee, could you be more precise with what you are trying to achieve? Add the extra details to the original question instead of in a comment so that we can better help you.

Comment: the code above is on "PostService.css". For now i`m trying to retrieve all my data from database into a view called AllHouses() using that method. 
The entities of House consist. Owner, Price, Location and Description. How can i get my data into GridView.

Comment: @Xion, Thanks for your clarification. Again, please add this extra information to the question itself so that it is immediately clear for everybody what it is that you are trying to achieve

Comment: thanks for the reply, but there are an error occur. it said that "The type or namespace name "House" could not be found ( are u missing using a directive or an assembly reference".
I has put the HouseList code into HouseList View.. and that error pop up to me. Did i miss out something? and sorry for the trouble again.

Comment: Well, you need to include a reference to the namespace where the class `House` is, somehting like for instance `using SomeNamespace.Entities`. What is the namespace of the class `House`?

Comment: The first code u write is put in Controller file rite? and 2nd code is put in HouseList.cshtml file right? the namespace of House Entities is namespace TemplateProject.Core.Entities. Where shall i include it? as i know.. controller file already included

Comment: @Xion, that's correct, the first code belongs in the controller and the second in `HouseList.cshtml`. I've updated my answer to include the necessary using statements